# Did author make a logical mistake in his explanation?

Tags: objective-c

I'm learning objective-c from "Programming in objective-c" author Kochan. 3rd edition.
In Chapter 8 "Inheritance" Mr. Kochan gives following explanation to the method:

```
-(void) setOrigin: (XYPoint *) pt
{
if (! origin)
origin = [[XYPoint alloc] init];
origin.x = pt.x;
origin.y = pt.y;
}
```

"*The method first tests to see if the instance variable origin is nonzero* (make sure you
understand that test and the use of the logical negation operator ! that’s used). Recall that
all instance variables are initially set to zero. So when a new Rectangle object is allocated,
its instance variables, which includes origin, will be set to zero.

*If the origin is zero*, the setOrigin: method will allocate and initialize a new
XYPoint object and store the reference to it in the origin."

Is there a logical mistake? Doesn't the "setOrigin" method allocates a new XYPoint object only if the origin is non zero?

Comment: I don't see any 'mistake' per-se here, but lazy loading. The code indentation you gave doesnt help, and generally speaking for trivial objects such as points, they should be initialized in the constructor, not the method where they are set. This is also a prime candidate for a `copy` call to be made instead of a member-wise copy, as that supports inheritance as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author is, indeed, correct.

This is why I don't like incomplete comparisons in C.

If he codes `if (origin)` then that boolean expression is true for any value of `origin` which is non-zero.

So, when he negates it, the boolean expression `if (! origin)` is true only when origin is zero.

IMO, this is horrendous and should be coded `if (origin == NULL)` which makes it much clearer.

It seems to me that he is going out of his way to teach bad coding habits. This sort of construct always gives off a [Code Smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell).

Comment: `origin` being an object, it is incorrect to compare it with integer 0. If you wish to make an explicit comparison, use `if( origin == nil )`. `if( !obj )` to test an object for validity is completely idiomatic, however.

Comment: As @JoshCaswell says, it is much more idiomatic to use `if ( !origin )`. Certainly `if (origin == nil)` would be preferable to `if ( origin == 0)`. If you are looking for "code smells" comparing a pointer to an integer is a good example.

Comment: @JoshCaswell +1 Yes, comparison to NULL is even better

Comment: Not really; `NULL` is for C pointers. `0 == NULL == nil` of course, but if you're talking about code smells, you need to use the correct zero value for the type. `origin` is an object. You represent "zero object" with `nil`.

Answer (score 5):

Your quote says:

> *If the origin is zero*, ...

That is, when `origin` is zero (`nil`), then `! origin` will be *true*, and a new `XYPoint` will be allocated.

I don't see a logical inconsistency here.

Comment: I would add that it will only set an origin if the origin is 0, it won't reset the origin.

Comment: Lets trust the guy with 238k rep

Comment: @TeenDev: I get stuff wrong all the time, but I don't often make the same error twice. :)

Comment: @Mr_Vlasov: yes, that's correct. Well, `origin == 0` since `=` is assignment.

Answer (score 1):

No. The "!" is a logical NOT operation in this case. When "origin" is zero, !origin is TRUE; when "origin" is non-zero, !origin is FALSE. Therefore, the next line (which allocates and initializes an XYPoint object) is only executed when origin is zero. Just as the author states.